# Replace '\n' by ',' in java

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I want to take input from user as `String` and replace the newline character `\n` with `,`

I tried :

`String test ="s1\ns2\ns3\ns4";
 System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\n",","));`

> Output was s1,s2,s3,s4

But when I try the same code by getting input from UI it's not working.

When I debug it the string test(which I hardcoded) is treated as,

s1

s2

s3

s4

but the string from UI is "`s1\ns2\ns3\ns4`".

Please suggest what is wrong.

Comment: try `System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\n",",").replaceAll("\r\n",",")); `

Comment: _"getting input from UI "_ - Show the code that gets the input from the UI.  Clearly whatever does the reading is not interpreting the escape code and leaving the literal `\n` in the string.  You may need to interpret escape sequences yourself

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\n` is the new line character. If you need to replace that actual backslash character followed by `n`, Then you need to use this:

```
String test ="s1\ns2\ns3\ns4";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\n",","));
```

> **Update:**

You can use the `System.lineSeparator();` instead of the `\n` character.

```
System.out.println(test.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(),","));
```

Comment: This is working fine when I give the string as hardcoded one. but when I get the string from user through textarea it's not working

Comment: please check the value of that string when you get from user through textArea.

Comment: Don't use \n but the a line separator as defined in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: You can use the `System.lineSeparator();` instead of the `\n` character.

Comment: I think in order to get `System.lineSeparator()` to work, the regex string has to be *formatted* like a regex. So something like `replaceAll("[" + System.lineSeparator() + "]+")`. That's the only way I could get it to work on my device.

Comment: System.lineSeparator() is dependent of the os where java is executed. In case of client/server activity like Web Development, you can't presume of the line terminator of the client with this method.

Answer (score 3):

java.util.regex.Pattern [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) specifies Line terminators as :

> A line terminator is a one- or two-character sequence that marks the
>   end of a line of the input character sequence. The following are
>   recognized as line terminators:
>
> A newline (line feed) character ('\n'),
>   A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character ("\r\n"),
>   A standalone carriage-return character ('\r'),
>   A next-line character ('\u0085'),
>   A line-separator character ('\u2028'), or
>   A paragraph-separator character ('\u2029).

Your line terminator, from textarea, are \r\n (CR/LF).

regex for that is `[\r\n]+`

Answer (score 1):

As anacron already pointed out '\n' is a special charachter and different to the user input "\n", because the user input is transformed to "\\n".

The Java String after user input will look like

```
String test ="s1\\ns2\\ns3\\ns4";
```

and not like your test string

```
String test ="s1\ns2\ns3\ns4";
```

The user will input single charachter and the keyboard '\' is transformed to Java charachter '\\'.

Comment: how can we replace \\n in this case?

Comment: @sony System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\n",","));

Comment: Thank you.. @Markus

Answer (score 1):

Using `Regex` :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "s1\ns2\ns3\ns4";
        str = str.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", ",");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

> outout : s1,s2,s3,s4

Answer (score 0):

If someone will get from UI \\n in text and want remove one \ to get next line sign \n then can use this:

```
        String text = "text\\ntext\\ntext\\ntext";
    System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n"));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAv8d.png